# RegEx for Flex Inspectable tag

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a RegExp that will match the following metadata tag (used in Flex but may be used other places).

```
Some text some more text [Inspectable(verbose="0",minValue="1",maxValue="100")] some text some text  [Inspectable(arrayType="String",category="Styles")] some text.
```

Here is what I have so far but it is capturing 1 single group instead of 2 the two of them.

([Inspectable((.*))])

PS I'm using [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ungreedy/reluctant quantifier:

```
(\[Inspectable\(.*?\)\])
```

Comment: Apparently SO doesn't think anyone can answer questions that quickly. "You can accept an answer in 10 minutes." Thanks SO you know better. /s

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: The delay is for the one who ask to confirm the answer before blindly accepting.

Comment: Thanks nhahtdh. FYI I did not blindly accept and I was able to confirm the answer right away.